# Dart type castings

Tags: dart

I try to implement mergeSort in dart. Here is my code:

```
    List mergeSort(List list)
    {
        if (list.length <= 1) return list;
        List left, right, result;
        int middle = list.length ~/ 2;

        left = mergeSort(list.getRange(0, middle));
        right = mergeSort(list.getRange(middle, list.length) as List);

        result = merge(left, right);
        return result;
    }
```

And I get an TypeError at this line:

```
        left = mergeSort(list.getRange(0, middle));
```

It seems that getRange() returns Iterable, but List implements Iterable what is the problem here, shouldn't it work?

Anyway when I try:

```
            left = mergeSort(list.getRange(0, middle) as List);
```

it still doesn't work and gives me a CastError. 
So my question is what's the problem here, and what's the Dart-style solution for it? 
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Iterable.toList()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Iterable#id_toList) should do the trick.

```dart
 left = mergeSort(list.getRange(0, middle).toList());
```

You can't directly cast an *Iterable* to a *List* because *Iterable* is a super type of *List*. 
You can cast an object to its parent class, but you cant cast an object to any of its child class.

**Example:**

```dart
var a = new AnyClass();
var o = new Object(); //Actually this is not correct, but let's imagine

(o as AnyClass).toString() //wont works
(a as Object).toString() //will works
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getRange` method returns an Iterable, not a List. Using `as List` does not change that, it just fails because its operand isn't actually a List.

You can use the [List.sublist](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.List#id_sublist) method to get a slice of a list as an actual List.

The collection package on pub also contains an implementation of merge-sort: `package:collection/algorithms.dart`.