# Flutter - How to parse JSON data to a base class?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm wondering how can I parse a JSON data to a base class, because I'm trying to write, but get Unhandled Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'WeatherModel' in type cast.
Here is my code:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}
```

```
import 'BaseModel.dart';

class WeatherModel extends BaseModel {
  String success;
  Result result;
  Records records;

  WeatherModel({this.success, this.result, this.records});
  @override
  fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    //...
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    //... parse to Json
    return data;
  }
}

}
```

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flightinfo/model/BaseModel.dart';

class HttpUtils {
 static Future<BaseModel> get(String url, Map<String, dynamic> params, BaseModel baseModel) async {
    try {
      print("url:$url,params:$params");
      Response response = await Dio().get(url, queryParameters: params);
      if (response != null && response.statusCode == 200) {
        baseModel.fromJson(response.data);
        print(baseModel);
        return baseModel;
      }
      print(response);
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

```
class WeatherRequest {
  Future<WeatherModel> get() async {
    return HttpUtils.get(_url, _params,new WeatherModel());
  }
}
```

I think `HttpUtils.get` direct to `BaseModel` for extensibility. This is very common in Java, but in Dart I get a exception in `WeatherRequest` in below line:

`return HttpUtils.get(_url, _params,new WeatherModel());`

> **Unhandled Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'WeatherModel' in type cast**

In Dart, how to take care of this cast?

Comment: this is because you are passing BaseModel in HttpUtils.get and in weatherRequest you are using WeatherModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be occurring because `get()` method of `WeatherRequest` returns a `Future` to `WeatherModel` but you have returned a `Future<BaseModel>` instead.

> Try adding `await` to resolve `Future` converting it to `BaseModel` before returning.

```js
return (await HttpUtils.get(_url, _params,new WeatherModel()) );
```

Also, as per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23958527/4353782):

> You can cast an object to its parent class, but you can't cast an object to any of its child class.

So implicit casting of `BaseModel` to `WeatherModel` may not work as expected. Instead, you can add a helper method to `BaseModel` like `BaseModel.toWeatherModel` and return a `WeatherModel`

```js
abstract class BaseModel {
  toWeatherModel(){
  //...
  }
}
```

Or modify `get` method of `WeatherRequest` to return `Future<BaseModel>`.

```js
class WeatherRequest {
  Future<BaseModel> get() async {
    return (await HttpUtils.get(_url, _params,new WeatherModel()));
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is on async method must use await([async and await](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#async-await)), after add await in return value, that's work. thanks : )
and I am not use BaseModel to helper like toWeatherModel, because If BaseModel have many sub class, that will add many toXXXModel in BaseModel, so I'm use second   the way.